# The complicated group of regular expression in R

Tags: regex, r

```
word<-"xyz9874w9874w"
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\1", word )
[1] "xyz874w"
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\2", word )
[1] "9874874w"
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\3", word )
[1] "w874w"
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\4", word )
[1] "9874w"
```

in my opinion:

- the first part ([a-z]+) matchs `xyz`;
- the second part ([0-9]+) matchs `9874`;
- the third part ([a-z])  matchs  `w`;
- the fourth part (\w)   matchs  `9874w`;

why the reslut is not :

```
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\1", word )  
[1] "xyz"  
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\2", word )  
[1] "9874"  
gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\\w)", "\\3", word )  
[1] "w"
```

it is right to add `*` in ([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\w)  ,to make it become ([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(\w*),
if there is no `*`  in my regular pattern ,how to understand the result?

Comment: `*` means "catch as many as you can of this thing (possibly zero)", while `+`, which you already know about, says "catch as many as you can of this thing (but only if there is at least one)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern using `\\w` is looking for any "word character" ( == `[[:alnum:]_]` ), while it appears you may want to look for an actual "w": The `\\w` is matching the "9" and the remaining characters "874w" are not being substituted. If you wanted to match to the remainder of the string, then why not ".+$" for the fourth capture group?

```
 gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(.+$)", "\\1", word )
[1] "xyz"
> gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(.+$)", "\\2", word )
[1] "9874"
> gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(.+$)", "\\3", word )
[1] "w"
> gsub( "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z])(.+$)", "\\4", word )
[1] "9874w"
```

Depending on the unstated "rules" of the underlying problem, it may add specificity to put a "^" as the leading pattern-character so that the matching begins with the first character.